# Sending direct messages from twitter API

Tags: php, twitter

I'm trying to send internal server notices via direct message to myself and another staff member through the API. I've gone through the API setup on dev.twitter and I've downloaded [abraham's twitteroauth](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) library.

Where do I need to be looking to send a message direct from the server (Through my account) without having to log in everytime with a browser? Last time I used the twitter API was before oauth, so quite some time has passed.

**tl;dr** Need to send direct messages through twitter without seeing this [image: Twitter button]

Comment: You can get your personal token from you app page on [dev.twitter.com](https://dev.twitter.com/apps) and use it without having to `Sign in with Twitter`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can get your personal tokens from you app page on [dev.twitter.com](https://dev.twitter.com/apps) and use it without having to `Sign in with Twitter`.

On your app page under the section `OAuth settings` get:

- the consumer key
- the consumer secret

And under `Your access token` get:

- the access token
- the access token secret

Check that the access level is `Read, write, and direct messages`. Otherwise change it in the `Settings` tab and recreate your access tokens (there is a button on the bottom of the `Details` tab).

Then in php

```
require('Abrahams library');

// Get everything you need from the dev.twitter.com/apps page
$consumer_key = 'APP KEY';
$consumer_secret = 'APP SECRET';
$oauth_token = 'YOUR TOKEN';
$oauth_token_secret = 'YOUR TOKEN SECRET';

// Initialize the connection
$connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);

// Send a direct message
$options = array("screen_name" => "theGuyIWantToDM", "text" => "Hey that's my message");
$connection->post('direct_messages/new', $options);
```